# MembershipProvider and PasswordRecovery control

Tags: .net, security, .net-2.0, asp.net-membership, passwords

I need help using the PasswordRecovery control in .net 2.0. My situation is the application has changed from storing the passwordformat in Hashed to Clear.

The problem is the newly created users have a clear password stored and there are still users with hashed passwords. When I use the passwordRecovery control as below for users who still have a hashed password, the 'PasswordFormat' field is NOT altered to 'clear'  for those previous users with hashed passwords.

```
<asp:PasswordRecovery MailDefinition-BodyFileName="/mailTemplates/changePassword.htm" MailDefinition-From="test@test.com" MailDefinition-Subject="Test" CssClass="noLines" ID="PasswordRecovery1" UserNameTitleText="" UserNameInstructionText="Enter User name and a new passord will be generated and mailed to the user"  runat="server" SuccessText="Your password has been sent to your registered email address." SubmitButtonStyle-CssClass="button" 
    onsendingmail="PasswordRecovery1_SendingMail" MembershipProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProviderF0005600">
    </asp:PasswordRecovery>

<membership>
  <providers>
    <remove name="AspNetSqlMembershipProviderF0005600"/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProviderF0005600" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" minRequiredPasswordLength="1" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordFormat="Clear" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have multiple password storage scheme in MembershipProvider. You must reset the passwords to all users having hasehd password and send them a newly auto-generated  password in their email with the username.

Either you must take all users' password to hasehd or to clear.

> **There must be uniform straegy for the
>   password storage for
>   MemberShipProviders.**

Comment: Hi thanks very much for your answer. Is there Microsoft documentation that also states your assertion that all passwords must be either hashed, clear or encrypted?

Comment: I have not come across one yet and I dont think it might even exists. A provider will have its own single mechanism to read and write passwords. So if it configured to do it in hashed mode it wont match the clear mode. It's not about whther it can do it or not, merely by just being able to read-write from db does not serve the purpose becuase db does not know the format.

Answer (score 1):

this.__curious_geek is correct.  You don't need Microsoft documentation to verify his assertion, it's inherent in the nature of hashed passwords.  Once a password has been hashed it *cannot* be recovered.  This is simply the nature of hashing--it's a one-way operation.  If it was two-way, it would be encryption--not hashing.

Therefore, if you switch from hashed passwords to plain text, you *must* reset everybody's password who had their password hashed.  There's no way to get their password back--they must be assigned a new password.